# Show that $\lim_{x \to c} x^{3}=c^{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Please check my proof

I will use the fact that

$\lim_{x \to c}x^{3}=c^{3}$ equivalent $\lim_{x \to c}x\lim_{x \to c}x\lim_{x \to c}=(c)(c)(c)$

for $\lim_{x \to c} x=c$ we

let $\epsilon >0$ and $\delta >0$

we have

$0<|x-c|<\delta \leftrightarrow |x-c|<\sqrt[3]{\epsilon }$

but in this case we want to proove $\lim_{x \to c}x^{3}=c^{3}$

We will have

$0<|x-c|<\delta \leftrightarrow |x-c|<\sqrt[3]{\epsilon }$

$0<|x-c|<\delta \leftrightarrow |x-c|<\sqrt[3]{\epsilon }$

now $\lim_{x \to c}x^{3}=c^{3}\rightarrow \lim_{x \to c}x\lim_{x \to c}x\lim_{x \to c}x=(c)(c)(c)$

$0<|x-c|<\delta \leftrightarrow |x-c||x-c||x-c|<\sqrt[3]{\epsilon }\sqrt[3]{\epsilon }\sqrt[3]{\epsilon }=\epsilon $

Comment: There you're using directly the fact that the limit of a product is the product of the limits, so your epsilon-delta notation is not needed actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an argument which does not use continuity. You are on the right track by observing that properties of limits give you
$$\lim_{x\to c}(x^3)=\left(\lim_{x\to c}x\right)^3\;.$$
Notice that its enough to calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to c}x$. We can simply plug that answer into the above equation and it will calculate the limit for us.

So we can forget about the rest of the problem and try to just calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to c}x$. But this is really easy to do using $\epsilon$, $\delta$ style argument.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and choose $\delta=\epsilon$. Then if $\vert x-c \vert<\delta$...well then $\vert x-c\vert<\delta=\epsilon$. Hence, by definition
$$\lim_{x\to c}x=c\;.$$

Now going back to the original problem, we conclude that
$$\lim_{x\to c}(x^3)=\left(\lim_{x\to c}x\right)^3=c^3\;.$$

Comment: @Fourier No problem.

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Use difference of cubes. 
$$ x^3 - c^3 = (x-c)(x^2 + xc + c^2)$$

The right term in the product is a polynomial i.e continuous and so it is bounded on $[c- \epsilon, c+ \epsilon]$ say by $M$. It now follows that,

$$ \forall \epsilon>0, |x-c|<\delta := \dfrac{\epsilon}{M} \Rightarrow |x^3 - c^3|< \frac{\epsilon}{M} \cdot M = \epsilon$$

$\textbf{Edit}$: I should not use the fact that $x^2+xc+c^2$ is a polynomial and so continuous as another user points out, since you could just say $x^3$ is continuous and so there is nothing to prove. Instead, get a bound for the polynomial in this manner, suppose $x\in (c-\epsilon, c+ \epsilon)$ then given $\epsilon >0$ you can always choose $M$ such that $M > |c| + \epsilon$ and so,

$$ |x^2 + xc + c^2| < M^2 + M^2+M^2 = 3M^2$$

Hence instead choose,

$$\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3M^2}$$

Comment: I have tried to use by factor it before but I found It 's difficult to prove for beginner like me -*- that why I used this method

Comment: Does the argument make sense? Factor $x^3 - c^3$ and then use the fact that continuous functions on bounded intervals attain their max and min on these intervals. So on $[c- \epsilon , c+ \epsilon]$ you know that $|x^2+xc+c^2|<M$ and so on $(c-\epsilon/M, c+\epsilon/M)$ this is also true since it is a smaller interval. Thus is you make $|x-c|<\epsilon/M$ then the product $|x-c| \cdot |x^2+xc+c^2|< \epsilon$.

Comment: He said "please check my proof". How is the "hint" you gave a hint at all to checking his proof? I'm so confused

Comment: @FaraadArmwood If you're going to employ properties of of continuous functions, then the function $f(x)=x^3$ is continuous, and so by definition the limit is $c^3$. I think it's better to use an argument which does not use continuity.

Comment: Does it has another method that does not used continuity ? I do not read deep detait about continuity yet - -

Comment: I have corrected my proof @user43687 you were exactly right. I should not have done that.

Answer (score 2):

More generally,
to show that
$\lim_{x \to c} x^n
= c^n$
for positive integral $n$.

$x^n-c^n
=(x-c)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k c^{n-1-k}
$.

Since we are considering
$x$ close to $c$,
we can assume that
$|x-c| < 1$
so that
$|x| < |c|+1$.

Then,
for such $x$,

$\begin{array}\\
|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k c^{n-1-k}|
&\le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |x^k c^{n-1-k}|\\
&\lt \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |(|c|+1)^k c^{n-1-k}|\\
&\lt n(|c|+1)^{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
|x^n-c^n|
&=|(x-c)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k c^{n-1-k}|\\
&=|x-c|\,|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k c^{n-1-k}|\\
&\lt|x-c|\,|n(|c|+1)^{n-1}|\\
\end{array}
$

so that,
if
$|x-c|
< \min\left(1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{n(|c|+1)^{n-1}}\right)
$,
then
$|x^n-c^n|
\lt \epsilon$.